# mysql query handling repetation

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem with a MySQL query.
I need to display the following output:

```
id | name  |     leave_date
-------------
1    sam         2011-11-22
2    david       2011-11-23
3    cooper      2011-11-27
4    sam         2011-11-30
```

My query is

```
select * from table1 where leave_date != "2011-11-22"
```

**NOTE:** YOU SHOULD NOT USE DIRECTLY THE "NAME".. I NEED TO ELIMINATE THE REPETITION

I get output like this:

```
id | name  |     leave_date
-------------
2    david       2011-11-23
3    cooper      2011-11-27
4    sam         2011-11-30
```

But I want to eliminate "sam", so output would be:

```
id | name  |     leave_date
-------------
2    david       2011-11-23
3    cooper      2011-11-27
```

Comment: what repetition? i don't see any repetition to the record with name sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from table1 where name not in
(select name from table1 group by name having count(*) > 1)
```

Comment: hi.........thanks peter... i got it......... thanks for your valauable answer..............

Comment: @PeterPeiGuo Glad it worked for him, but I am curious how this works exactly. Where does the check for the leave_date go?

Answer (score 0):

> but i want to eliminate "sam" and output would be

```
select * 
from table1
where name <> 'sam'
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to eliminate sam record based on what logic?

Not having a business logic condition based on what to eliminate sam, the only way to do it is similar to:

```
select * from table1 where leave_date!="2011-11-22" and name <> 'sam'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. If anyone has a prettier way, feel free to edit:

```
SELECT * from table1 WHERE leave_date != "2011-11-22" 
AND name NOT IN (SELECT name from table1 WHERE leave_date = "2011-11-22")
```